# Build complex queries with multiple fields in cloudant

Tags: cloudant

```
Date          State       |   City    |  Zip |   Water |  Weight 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
01/01/2016    Arizona     Chandler    1011    10 ltr    40 kg     
01/04/2016    Arizona     Mesa        1012    20 ltr    50 kg

06/05/2015    Washington  Spokane     1013    30 ltrs   44 kg

06/08/2015    Washington  Spokane     1013    30 ltrs   44 kg
```

What I want are complex queries, like I want to know average water, weight by passing a city or state or ip for a date range or month, or any field or all fields.

I am not sure how to go about this. Read about map reduce, but cant guess how will I get above output

If you have link for examples which covers above scenarios that will also help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: so you want **complex queries**. What level of complexity do you want in those queries?

Answer (score 1):

So first we need to model your structured data in JSON. Something like this would work:

```
{
  "date": "2016-01-01",
  "location": "Arizona Chandler",
  "pressure": 1101,
  "water": 10,
  "weight": 40
}
```

Here's your data in a Cloudant database:

https://reader.cloudant.com/so37613808/_all_docs?include_docs=true

Next we'd need to create a MapReduce view to aggregate the a specific field by date. A map function to create an index whose key is the date and whose value is the `water` would look like this:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.date, doc.water);
}
```

Every key/value pair emitted from the map function is added to an index which can be queried later in its entirety or by a range of keys (keys which in this case represent a date).

And if an average is required we would use the built-in `_stats` reducer. The Map and Reduce portions are expressed in a Design Document like this one: https://reader.cloudant.com/so37613808/_design/aggregate

The subsequent index allows us to get an aggregate across the whole data set with:

https://reader.cloudant.com/so37613808/_design/aggregate/_view/waterbydate

Dividing the `sum` by the `count` gives us an average.

We can use the same index to provide data grouped by keys too:

https://reader.cloudant.com/so37613808/_design/aggregate/_view/waterbydate?group=true

Or we can select a portion of the data by supplying `startkey` and `endkey` parameters:

https://reader.cloudant.com/so37613808/_design/aggregate/_view/waterbydate?startkey=%222016-01-01%22&endkey=%222016-06-03%22

See https://docs.cloudant.com/creating_views.html for more details.

Comment: Hello, Let me try this.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input.

Comment: Getting the desired output